# Function invoked by Pyspark map do not modify global list

Tags: python, apache-spark, lambda, pyspark, global-variables

I have defined this function that operates on the global list *signature*, I have tested the function and it works.

```
def add_to_list_initial(x):
    global signature
    signature.append([x])
    print(x)
    return x
```

The print will check if the function is invoked.

I have to run this function for each row of a Pyspark rdd, so I written this code:

```
rdd.map(lambda x: min([str(int.from_bytes(hash_functions[0](str(shingle)), 'big')) for shingle in x])).map(lambda x: add_to_list_initial(x))
```

But the function is not invoked so, to avoid the "laziness" of map, I tried to add ".count()" at the end, in this way:

```
rdd.map(lambda x: min([str(int.from_bytes(hash_functions[0](str(shingle)), 'big')) for shingle in x])).map(lambda x: add_to_list_initial(x)).count()
```

And now the print is done. I have even checked that list *signature* is updated but, when I try to print the size of the list, the result will be 0, because the list is not updated at all.

I have even tried to use *foreach* instead of *map*, but the result is the same:

```
rdd1 = rdd.map(lambda x: min([str(int.from_bytes(hash_functions[0](str(shingle)), 'big')) for shingle in x]))
rdd1.foreach(add_to_list_initial)
```

These are the firsts lines of the output, they are written in red on my Pycharm console, even the prints:

```
19/11/19 21:56:51 WARN TaskSetManager: Stage 2 contains a task of very large size (76414 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB.
1000052032941703168135263382785614272239884872602
1001548144792848500380180424836160638323674923493
1001192257270049214326810337735024900266705408878
1005273115771118475643621392239203192516851021236
100392090499199786517408984837575190060861208673
1001304115299775295352319010425102201971454728176
1009952688729976061710890304226612996334789156125
1001064097828097404652846404629529563217707288121
1001774517560471388799843553771453069473894089066
1001111820875570611167329779043376285257015448116
1001339474866718130058118603277141156508303423308
1003194269601172112216983411469283303300285500716
1003194269601172112216983411469283303300285500716
1003194269601172112216983411469283303300285500716
1003194269601172112216983411469283303300285500716
1003194269601172112216983411469283303300285500716
```

How can I resolve in an efficient way?
I use Python 3.7 and Pyspark 3.2.1

I'm doing this in order to obtain a min-hash signature for each set of hashed shingles, where the id of the document is

Then, to compute the other permutations, I think to act in this way:

```
def add_to_list(x):
    global num_announcements
    global signature
    global i
    print(len(signature))
    if i == num_announcements:
        i = 0
    signature[i].append(x)
    print(i)
    i += 1


for function in hash_functions[1:]:
    rdd.map(lambda x: min([str(int.from_bytes(function(str(shingle)), 'big')) for shingle in x])).foreach(add_to_list)
```

But the problem is the same. 
I will be glad even to have suggestions for my minhashing problem, but the question is about the problem described above.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved in this way, even if I did not find a useful solution for the problem in general.

```
signatures = shingles.flatMap(lambda x: [[(x[1]+1, (x[1]+1)%lsh_b), min([int.from_bytes(function(str(s)), 'big') for s in x[0]])] for function in hash_functions]).cache()
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of a global variable, you can use a class (a [*Callable*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Callable)).

For instance:

```py
from collections.abc import Callable


class Signature(Callable):
    def __init__(self):
        self.signature = []

    def __call__(self, x):
        self.signature.append([x])
        return x
```

Then, you can instanciate this callable where you need it:

```py
add_to_list_initial = Signature()

rdd.map(lambda x: min([str(int.from_bytes(hash_functions[0](str(shingle)), 'big')) for shingle in x])).map(
    lambda x: add_to_list_initial(x)
).count()

print(add_to_list_initial.signature)
```

Note: you can avoid a lambda expression here, an simplify with:

```py
rdd.map(lambda x: min([str(int.from_bytes(hash_functions[0](str(shingle)), 'big')) for shingle in x])).map(
    add_to_list_initial
).count()
```

**EDIT**

To allow pickling, you can use:

```py
class Signature:
    def __init__(self):
        self.signature = []

    def __call__(self, x):
        self.signature.append([x])
        return x
```

Comment: I obtain this error: > _pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: can't pickle _abc_data objects

Comment: OK, so remove the import (`from collections.abc import Callable`) and the inheritance. Use `class Signature:` without the super-class `Callable`.

Comment: Same problem, returns an empty list, but if I insert a print it will print the full list at the end of each iteration. I think it is a pyspark "problem" because I do not know how to force the self.signature modification because it considers that operation "useless"